# How to simplify this regular expression?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

How do i prove that the regular expression $$a^*(ba^*)^*$$ is the same as $$(a+b)^*$$. Is there a way to prove this using regular expression identities?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the second expression generates all strings made of $a$ and $b$.

Now, by induction, with the first expression:

- you can generate the empty string $\epsilon$, as $a^0(ba^*)^0$;
- any string generated with this expression can be appended with a $b$, which is $(ba^0)^1$;
- any string generated with this expression can be appended with a $a$:

  - either the string is $a^*$, and $a^*a=a^*$,
  - or the string is $a^*(ba^*)^+$, and $a^*(ba^*)^+a=a^*(ba^*)^*(ba^*)a=a^*(ba^*)^*(ba^*)=a^*(ba^*)^+$.